# Explicación ciclo for anidado javascript

Tags: javascript

alguien me puede dar una peque;a explicacion de como funciona este for anidado

```
function piramide(numPisos) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numPisos; i++) {
    let piso = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
      piso = piso + '#';
    }
    console.log(piso)
  }
}
piramide(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

La función te dibuja una pirámide en la consola.

Si le pasas el parámetro 7 ocurrirá lo siguiente.

En la primera iteración i valdrá 0, luego entrará en el bucle anidado que tendrá como condición de parada j < 1 (luego sólo hará una iteración) por tanto la variable piso valdrá #.

En la siguiente iteración i valdrá 1, por lo que el bucle anidado parará cuando j = 1 ( j < 2). Por tanto la variable piso tendrá el valor ##.

De esta manera cada iteración irá añadiendo una cadena # más que la anterior y se acabará mostrando en la consola algo así

[image: resultado]

Comment: gracias bro ya me quedo mucho mas claro